# Flex layout overflow outer container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hxknmzfd/5/) showing my code.
It works as I want : basically it is a container with 1 row item that takes 100% widht, and two items with fixed width.
If the container is big enough they should stay in line, otherwise they should wrap.

I don't get why when my viewport gets smaller the two smaller blocks  start to overflow on the side outside the container and they don't shrink as I expect.
I tried to remove the fixed width and using flex-basis, but It breaks the layout.

This is the code on the fiddle:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="search-form flex-row">
        <span class="block big">hi</span>
        <div class="flex-block">
          <span class="block">hi</span>
          <span class="block">hi</span>
        </div>

        <span class="block">hi</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    padding:50px;
}
.search-form {
    /* margin-bottom: 0px; */
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color:blue;

}
.flex-row {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.flex-block{
 display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.block{
    flex-shrink:1;
    width:150px;
    background-color:red;
    margin:5px;
}
.block.big{
    width:100%
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why you refer to "rows" but are using `flex-direction:column`. You have fixed widths on the blocks...flexbox isn'tgoing to override that.

Comment: I talk about rows because basically the first one is one element row, and the second is a two element row. Then they wrap as one element per rows, so like a normal column layout.

Comment: Well as I said, you have fixed widths...not much you can do about that other than rethinking what you are after (which is not clear to me) and, perhaps, the way you are going about it.

Answer (score 0):

Sry, I don't have 50 reputations, that's why I need to awnser.

**First** (maybe) problem:

did you put the meta tag for viewport in the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

**Second** (maybe) compromise:

maybe you can work with `min-width`?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 0):

Simple math: `100% + 100px` = *too much*

```
.container{
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    padding:50px; /* Issue */
}
```

to the rescue you can use

***[fiddle demo using border-box](http://jsfiddle.net/hxknmzfd/8/)***

```
*{margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

or

***[fiddle demo using calc()](http://jsfiddle.net/hxknmzfd/7/)***

```
.container{
    height:100vh;
    width: calc(100% - 100px); /* cause 50padd + 50padd = 100 */
    padding:50px;
}
```